# Find most recent SFTP file with a particular filename using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I have a folder on an SFTP server that has a bunch of files.  There are 6 different files, and they are created every 60min.  Each with a date and time stamp, and they are held for 3 days.

```
FilesCodes_Critical.2022-03-17_11-16-22-614.json
FilesCodes_Critical.2022-03-17_12-12-16-818.json
FilesCodes_Critical.2022-03-17_13-11-43-025.json
TransactionAudit.2022-03-14_11-16-23-530.json
TransactionAudit.2022-03-14_12-12-19-764.json
TransactionAudit.2022-03-14_13-11-45-454.json
```

I am creating a few processes that will run every hour and will pick up a particular file and process it.  I know I can use the `Name.StartsWith` to grab the correct file, but I can't figure out how to grab the most recent of them.  I was thinking that `LastWriteTime` could be used, but I can't figure out how to compare it.

```
fileNamePat = "FileCodes_Critical";    

try {       
    sftpc.Connect();

    var files = sftpc.ListDirectory(sFTPPath);
    foreach (SftpFile file in files)
    {
        if (file.Name.StartsWith(fileNamePat))
        {
            string jsonData = sftpc.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
            DataSet ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonData);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I thought of trying something like this to compare and put the final file into `targetFile`

```
if (file.Name.StartsWith(fileNamePat))
{
    if (file.LastWriteTime > targetFile.LastWriteTime)
    {
        targetFile = file;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out where/how to create the `SftpFile targetFile` so the comparison will work.  I tried `SftpFile targetFile = new();` and thought I could check to see if it was blank and then set it, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a lambda on your set of files:

```
foreach (SftpFile file in files.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(fileNamePat))
                                 .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastWriteTime)
                                   .Take(1)) 
{ 
      [...]
}
```

Actually you didn't need a for each. you can get your 'target' from lambda:

```
SftpFile targetFile = files.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(fileNamePat))
               .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastWriteTime)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Beautiful, I had no idea the `OrderByDescending` even existed!